# Xcode Error with slideviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sidebar, identifier

I am new to Xcode and I keep getting this error and I am not quite sure what it means and how to fix it:

Below is the link to the code error(http://pastebin.com/Y74frJxa) ...

```
2014-01-26 00:23:16.183 SidebarDemo[677:70b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:5261
2014-01-26 00:23:16.186 SidebarDemo[677:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier map - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0 CoreFoundation 0x0222a5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x016a48b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2 CoreFoundation 0x0222a448 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
3 Foundation 0x01077fee -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethodbject:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
4 UIKit 0x002e9ed3 -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 170
5 SidebarDemo 0x0000d6e9 -[SidebarViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 233
6 UIKit 0x002f461f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 412
7 UIKit 0x002f46f3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
8 UIKit 0x002d8774 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2378
9 UIKit 0x002ebe95 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
10 UIKit 0x00270267 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
11 libobjc.A.dylib 0x016b681f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
12 QuartzCore 0x029ed2ea -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
13 QuartzCore 0x029e10d4 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
14 QuartzCore 0x029e0f40 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
15 QuartzCore 0x02948ae6 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
16 QuartzCore 0x02949e71 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
17 QuartzCore 0x02a06430 +[CATransaction flush] + 52
18 UIKit 0x00221dc9 _afterCACommitHandler + 131
19 CoreFoundation 0x021f24ce __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
20 CoreFoundation 0x021f241f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
21 CoreFoundation 0x021d0344 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
22 CoreFoundation 0x021cfac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
23 CoreFoundation 0x021cf8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
24 GraphicsServices 0x027c59e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
25 GraphicsServices 0x027c5809 GSEventRun + 104
26 UIKit 0x00205d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
27 SidebarDemo 0x0000c76d main + 141
28 libdyld.dylib 0x0386a70d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Thank you to all who help in advance!

Comment: It Says it missing **Identifier** of Cell.

Answer (score 0):

The error says you are missing `reuseIdentifier`. For this,
 just select `tableViewCell` in `yourTableView` in Storyboard and set `reuseIdentifier` in attributes Inspector.

use that reuse identifier in `cellForRowAtIndex` method as

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"xxxx"]
```